# Mysql getting disconnected from application during populating

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

Recently i got mac m1
i am running a product which uses mysql@5.7 installed through homebrew, the data from the product is connected successfully to mysql and started populating but nearing the end of population there is a connection problem with mysql and shows exception during getconnection from pool am using mac m1 and mysql5.6

the error is as follows

java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.Exception: Exception during getConnection from pool Exception occurred during get connection from datasource
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

This dosnt occur at product startup but during 80% of population.

config file my.cnf

```
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: How many connections do you have in your pool, and how many of them are busy - e.g. never returned?

Comment: how can i check that?

Comment: Which pool are you using? Seems like an unhelpful error message

Comment: instead of going one-by-one: Check my answer. If you need more details, please edit your question with a [mcve] - please check [ask]: Currently you're providing nothing more than an error message, which doesn't make this a good and answerable question (though I've tried).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2983248/13447). I can't vote to close as duplicate, because I've already voted to close for a lack of information (see comments on my answer), but Revision 3 of the question suggests a different cause than revisions 1 and 2.

Comment: Thank you @OlafKock, i have finally found the root problem posted the answer,Appology for not sharing much detail as it is a third party app while having access to only log files, And as i have seen some questions like this(configuration problems) i thought i could use stack overflow and i dont know i coulldnt ask anything out of core programing like this one.

Answer (score 1):

Check **max_connections** in the MySQL configuration file. It manages the number of simultaneous connections according to the demands of your application.

Comment: have shared the file there is no key named max_connection

Comment: even though increased the problem stil the same

Answer (score 1):

After some long struggle and research fond the problem, the solutions from above, to increase max_connections and others dosnt worked out for me, sorry i couldnt share the code or any other info its a 3rd party application i had only access to the log files. So comming to the problem the problem was partly with my mac.

There is this parameter called `table_open_cache` and is related to `max_connections`. For example, for 200 concurrent running connections, we should specify a table cache size of at lease **200 * N**, where **N** is the maximum number of tables per join in any of the queries which we execute. We must also reserve some file descriptors for temporary tables and files

Where the problem occured for me is my OS (i.e MAC) couldnt handle all the number of open file descriptors implied by the `table_open_cache` settings or the default specified in **my.cnf**. In my case the default `table_open_cache` is set too high, MYSQL ran out of file descriptors and exhibited symptoms such as refusing connections or failing to perform queries. thats why the sudden connection loss during populating.

**SOLUTION** : I reduced my `table_open_cache` variable to a lower value like **400** in my.cnf file and restarted mysql server once and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

A connection pool provides you with a certain (configured, maximum) number of connections to the database.

The assumption is: When you're done with a connection, you're going to return it to the pool. This might be done implicitly by the garbage collector, but for a long running process, there's no guarantee that the garbage collector ever runs during your routine.

If your code uses the connections up like candy and never returns them (typically through `connection.close()`), or uses new connections for each operation rather than reusing a single connection, you're able to quickly exhaust the connection pool. This is called "resource leaking".

Raising the number of available connections (as suggested in the other answer) *might* help you *right now*, but will fail again, a bit later, when your routine populates the database with more data, if those routines still chew up connections.

As you neither provide configuration details nor code, that's as much answer as can be given.

Comment: how can i get the configuration details?

Comment: It's _your_ system, you should know, no? And I would recommend that you'd rather look at code eating connections like candy, rather than provide more candy (which would require configuration). That being said, there are several candidate places for the configuration, `tomcat/conf` is one place to look at, but it might be elsewhere. If necessary, you would need to get help to provide the necessary details to get an answer here - Stackoverflow is not a consulting service, but a Q&A site for programming-related questions. And it looks like you have a programming issue - but I still see no [mcve].

Comment: thank you for your response there is no keys regarding maximum connection pool as i have edited the question with my.cnf file

Comment: The connection _pool_ would be configured on the Tomcat side. And: it _might not_ be configured, so that run it with default values that you wouldn't find anywhere in your tomcat's configuration. Inspect your code.

Comment: lemme give a situation even though the code is clean using single instance of connection what if i use multiple application on mysql for example i can use my application and an DBeaver instance connected to mysql at the same time.. in that case too the problem occurs, what if i connect more application for analysisi what should be done in that case?

Comment: _If_ your code is indeed clean, you're on the wrong site: Stackoverflow is about programming issues, not about server maintenance. Now that you also added the "Communication Link Failure" information to the question, _and_ claim your code is clean (without providing any code or details), the question seems to be either off-topic for not being programming related, or to be closed for lack of a [mcve] (see [ask] and [help/on-topic])